# Can we bind single cucumber step to two different methods in two different classes

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I have two Feature files in my project where one step is common in these two files but I need to call two different Step definition function depending upon the file on which that steps was written.

do we have any configuration to do that?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you have 1 line in cucumber which needs to execute two different methods? For as far as I know this is not possible. Cucumber will keep on telling you there are multiple methods with the same name. - This is what I get from your title.

What I get from your explanation is something different. So you have 2 feature files with a common step. One feature file is getting its steps from classfile A and other feature file is getting its steps from classfile B?

In this case, you can best extend your public classes so you can use any code from any class file in any feature file.

Comment: Nope Anand it quite different, I have one step conman in both files and I want to execute a method depending upon the scenario.  Ex  add 10 from Maths.feature should execute method form MathsStepDef.java and add 10 from operation substract.feature should execute method from SubstractStepdef.java

Comment: Please share some code that describe what you want.

And remember that Cucumber will find the method wherever it is defined.

Two steps in one scenario will trigger two method calls. These methods may be defined in two different classes.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I could think this would be possible (but I don't recommend it) is to define some variable to to track which scenario you are running from. For instance, you could add a tag to each of the scenarios.

```
  @some_tag
  Scenario: This is scenario 1
    Given I do this thing

  @some_other_tag
  Scenario: This is scenario 2
    Given I do this thing
```

then you could create a hook that keeps track

```
Before('@some_tag') do
  @this = "foo"
end

Before('@some_other_tag') do
  @this = "bar"
end
```

Then from your step you run code depending on the value of the @this var.

```
Given(/^I do this thing$/) do
  if @this.eql? "foo"
    <do some code>
  elsif @this.eql? "bar
    <do something else>
  else
    <do other things>
end
```

But truly, after all that ... You should just have two different steps

```
Given I do this Foo Thing
```

and

```
Given I do this Bar Thing
```

It would help to better describe what the test is actually doing.